# How would I link to my home_controller.rb's contact action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails url helper, how would I link to my home_controller.rb's contact action?

1. how to generate the link
2. how to just get the path?
3. how to do a redirect to in an action?

thanks for clearing this up!

So far my home controller looks like:

```
resources :home do
    collection do
      get 'about'
      get 'contact'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you're looking for are:

```
contact_home_index_url
```

and

```
contact_home_index_path
```

To find these (and to see all other routes), use `rake routes` at the command line. On the right, you'll see the action and controller; find the line you need, take the variable on the left, and append `_path` or `_url` to the end as needed. For nested routes, you'll need to supply an argument, like:

```
new_event_boat_path(@event)
```

As for redirecting from a controller, try:

```
def redirect_sample
  redirect_to contact_home_index_url
end
```

Comment: thanks, strange the it has 'index' in it! i.e contact_home_index_path, I thought it would be contact_home_path

Comment: why would this fail?   <%= show_article_index_path(article) %> where article is from a .each loop i.e.  @articles.each do |article|

Comment: you need to use a link_to helper: `<%= link_to "Link Name", show_article_index_path(article) %>`

Comment: but I want just the path to be outputted, not the href tag.

Comment: ah, then use `<%= url_for show_article_index_path(article) %>`